# filtered listview onListItemClick returns Item at original position

Tags: android, listview, filter

I have a listview with custom rows being populated from an custom BaseAdaptor. On click of any row, I open a new Activity with a fragment. Everything was working fine until I added the filter functionality to this list. When I search the list and THEN click on an Item, it doesn't open the activity associated with the filtered results. It open up an Activity related to the Item at that position in Original list.

Eg. - Original List : AA, BA, CC, DA, ED, FF

Search : 'A' Filtered results: AA, BA, DA

But when I click on item DA it opens up the Activity for CC. Extremely irritating. I have called notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

in main acitvity

```
public class MainActivity_list extends FragmentActivity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

in headline fragment

```
// The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout

}
```

custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context context;
ArrayList<RowItem> rowItem;

ArrayList<RowItem> mStringFilterList;
ValueFilter valueFilter;




CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RowItem> rowItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItem = rowItem;
    mStringFilterList = rowItem;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return rowItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return rowItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);

    RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
    // setting the image resource and title

    txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());

    Picasso
            .with(context)

            .load(Ipsum.url[position])
            .fit() // will explain later

            .centerCrop()
            .into(imgIcon);



    return convertView;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<RowItem> filterList = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ( (mStringFilterList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase() )
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    RowItem rowItem = new RowItem(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getTitle());

                    filterList.add(rowItem);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values = mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        rowItem = (ArrayList<RowItem>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the callback implemented ?

Comment: i add all main acitivty with the clallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the position in the filtered dataset is point to a different object in the original dataset. If you don't want to change the main logic, what you can do is to change your `onArticleSelected` to take as parameter an instance `RowItem` instead of `position` and change your onListItemClick like

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    mCallback.onArticleSelected((RowItem)l.getItemAtPostion(position));

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout

}
```

this will retrieve a pass the correct object to your Activity

Comment: This code lets me change " int " in " RowItem " in main activity but the " position " in this line      args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);           gives me error

Comment: is RowItem parcelable? If is not check to make it parcelable and then use args.putParcelable

Comment: I do not understand what you mean ( sorry) .
I do not think it parcelable

Comment: Parcelable is a special way that Android provides you to pass object through intent/bundle.

Comment: you can read more about it [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable). AndroidStudio has a plugin that does it automatically. You might want to check it out

Comment: I tried ... but still do not understand how to implement the project nle me ... I'm sorry ! Thanks for your help

Comment: which part you didn't understand ? Could you describe the issue ?

Comment: I do not understand how to implement parcelable... so many days I look for a solution but nothing . you are very kind ! I ask you a big favor ! even if I put the code RowItem , you drive me or make me see in practice what should I do ? very sorry for the request ! ( Even live chat if you prefer ) thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

For those who use public void **onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)**

```
 private void setUpAdapter()
  {
    adapter2 = new CustomAdapter2(kafani, getApplicationContext());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Log.e("C pozicija ",""+ position) ;
    Log.e("C id",""+id) ;

  //  Kaf kafana = (Kaf) listView.getItemAtPosition(position); 

    Kaf kafana = (Kaf) kafani.get((int) id); // where kafani is ORIGINAL LIST, so I use the id
    String pozicija = String.valueOf(id);  

    // String pozicija = String.valueOf(position); 

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndiecZaKaf.this, KafDetails.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("parent", "A");
    myIntent.putExtra("pozicija", pozicija);
    myIntent.putExtra("imek",kafana.getImek());
    myIntent.putExtra("adresa",kafana.getAdresa());
    myIntent.putExtra("tel",kafana.getTelBroj());

    startActivity(myIntent);
  }
});
```